# How to stop program to open every time I log in to Windows?

Tags: windows, operating-system, customization

I had to download a program called Start All Back because I needed some customizations on my Windows 11. Now the trial period is over and although you don`t need to purchase a license to keep using it, it keeps opening up every single time I log in to Windows. This results in the Start All Back window appearing every time I log in, which is extremely annoying given that I might log in and out of my computer multiple times a day.

Does anyone know how I can stop that from happening?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to remove the Autostart of this program by either open the windows settings, go to Apps in left panel, look for Autostart on the right side and disable the entry of this program - or you might access this using the task manager (Key combo Ctrl+Shift+Esc) and look for Autostart in the left menu.